# Can I play iTunes song previews in an HTML page?

Tags: javascript, html, itunes-store, itunes-search-api

I need to show on my site search results from the iTunes Store, including previews of audio tracks.

I could use the [iTUnes search api](http://www.apple.com/itunes/affiliates/resources/documentation/itunes-store-web-service-search-api.html) to return JSON info with cover image, title and other info. But for previews url I have problems (like following http://a5.mzstatic.com/us/r1000/007/Music/2f/18/8c/mzm.dsmmvsnn.aac.p.m4a).

It is not direct link to file but to some streaming server (not sure it is RTSP, network sniffer shows some other). It could not be dowloaded directly by browser, flash and HTML5 players don’t support it, and it couldn't be opened even using QuickTime Player. So I haven't found any way to embed it to site web page like I do for regular audio/video links.

The only program that could open such urls is iTunes. But as far as I could see it couldn't be used as embed/object in browser/web page.

Any ideas how it could be implemented?

Answer (score 1):

As far as I understand iTunes not allows previews to be played for countries with no iTunes store.
So preview plays in Itunes application and not in quick time or any other player. So such case really difficult to catch (if it will not play in itunes app it will be clear and easy to detect, but in this case not).

After using proxy or just testing from other location all become working. And could be integrated using many flash players.

Comment: Interesting, I’m kind of surprised the previews aren’t DRMed. I would assume using the preview URL in a web page is against Apple’s Terms of Service (although I could be entirely wrong).